# SQL Server r dataframe integration

Tags: r, sql-server, connection

I'm trying to replicate a large R dataframe (1M Rows +) into SQL Server, however it hasn't been working out so far. I have used "odbcConnect" for R to read in SQL queries which works great. Afterwards I do the data manipulation/aggregation/model building to derive out a final set. Any suggestions/tests would be really helpful. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the Sql Server R server to call your R script using the sp_execute_external_script
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/advanced-analytics/tutorials/rtsql-using-r-code-in-transact-sql-quickstart?view=sql-server-2017